# Automorphism group of groups of order 42

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I would like to find an abstract solution for the following question:

> If $G$ is a group of order $42$, then  $5$ does not divide the order of ${\rm Aut}(G)$.

Comment: Can you explain What is your observation on this??

Comment: Let us go with a slightly less complicated version. Suppose G is cyclic, can you see that 5 does not divide order of Automorphism group.

Comment: Actually we know the structure of automorphism group of cyclic groups, and it is easy to check. About the group of order 42, I can check easily by GAP but I would like to know an abstract proof.

Comment: Excuse me if my way is misleading... i misread the question so, did not understand your intention..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps for an approach:

1. Show that $G$ has a unique, hence normal subgroup $P$ of order seven.
2. If $\phi\in Aut(G)$ satisfies $\phi^5=1$, show that $\phi$ maps $P$ to itself and that $\phi_P$ is the identity mapping.
3. We can deduce (why?) that $\phi$ induces an automorphism of $G/P$. Show that this must also be the identity mapping (use what you know about groups of order six to do this step).
4. Show that $\phi$ must be the identity mapping by combining steps 2, 3, and whatever else is required.

Comment: Dear Jyrki Lahtonen, I really enjoy your answer. Thanks a million.

Comment: @jyrki Lahtonen : @2, I see that any automorphism of G maps $P$ to $P$ (as it is unique subgroup of given order). But, I some how do not see immediately why $\phi^5=1$ implies $\phi$ is identity on $P$. could you please help me out.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen :) Excuse me for my negligence. Thank You

Comment: You're welcome, @Tina. I hope you caught the "extras" in step 4.